# Route53 mapping to regional custom domain not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I tried to follow steps mentioned in documentation below
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html

created certificate as per ACM documentation for my region, and created a regional api gateway with custom domain name, still I am not able to map my api gateway to route53 a recordset.

As mentioned in docs we can not map regional custom domain name to a recordset from UI but it is also giving error below from CLI

An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Tried to create an alias that targets d-xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com., type A in zone ABCDEFGH, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that you are not specifying the correct hosted-zone-id for your alias target.

For `ap-south-1`, the correct value is `Z3VO1THU9YC4UR`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#apigateway_region